# How to use Nginx proxy with multi sites and two servers?

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've installed nginx proxy in a VPS (Ubuntu 12.04 + Nginx 1.1.19) in order to send requests:

A- from (site1.com, site2.com and site3.com) to SERVER_A

B- from (site4.com, site5.com and site6.com) to SERVER_B

I used /etc/nginx/proxy.confg file with content:

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

also in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled I created first file configuration with:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name site1.com site2.com site3.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;


        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://IP_of_SERVER_A/;
                include         /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
}
```

It works fine till here. The problem comes when I try to add second file configuration with:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name site4.com site5.com site6.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;


        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://IP_of_SERVER_B/;
                include         /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
}
```

**Now:**
sites in second file doesn't works and all requests from (site4.com, site5.com site6.com) goes to server_A too.

Any help to add missing parts?

Comment: Did you restart Nginx after adding the second file? It feels like the SERVER_A proxy is being used as the default server (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: Yes restarted but error still the same.